# Select Multiple, get selected values and non-selected values

Tags: grails

I have a select multiple on my page. The user can add elements to the list and remove them selecting one or more.

When I get the select's value through params.selectName, I receive only the selected ones. I 
understand that this is the default behavior, but I need all of them, not only selected elements.

I don't really want to select all elements each time I send data to server. Does anyone have a better solution? Thanks.

Comment: Since you presumably have all of the values in the Grails app, why not just compare the list of selected ones from the full list in the DB?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a complex solution to what should be a simple problem, but in my current project we just had the same problem and solved it as @cdeszaq describes.

Assuming an object of class `Foo` with a collection (`bars`) of `Bar` items, where each `Bar` has a `String name` and outputs it as its `toString()` representation, we do this in the `FooController`:

```
def removedItems = fooInstance.bars.findAll {
    !params.bars.collect { it.key }.contains(it.name)
}

if(removedItems){
    removedItems.each {
        fooInstance.removeFromBars(it)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach taken by the `<g:checkBox>` tag is to create a hidden field with the same name as the checkbox but with an underscore prepended.  You could use a similar trick here, i.e. whenever you add a new `<option>` to the `<select>` you also add a hidden field named (say) `selectName_options` with the same value.  Then in the controller you can take the difference between `params.list('selectName')` and `params.list('selectName_options')` to get the un-selected options from the list.